# verify signing chain with pem

Tags: node.js, signing, ca

I need to verify a signing chain mit pem in nodejs.
I found the function `pem.verifySigningChain(certificate, ca, callback)`.
But how do I use callback to give me the message that the signing chain is correct or the test failed?
Has anyone a simple example?

**EDIT**

```
db.getCert(certificate, function(certificate) {
        if (certificate){
                db.getCaCert(caCert, function(caCert) {
                        if (caCert){
                                pem.verifySigningChain(certificate, caCert, function (err){
                                  if(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                  }
                                  console.log("Signing Chain okay");
                                 })
                          }
                      }
                 }
         }
```

Comment: As described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/pem#verify-a-certificate-signing-chain, you can use `function (err, result)` where result is boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Hopes it helps you.

```
var pem = require('pem');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem');
var ca = fs.readFileSync('ca.pem');

pem.verifySigningChain(cert, ca, function (err, result) {
  if (err){
     console.log('Error: '+err)
  }  else{
     //here result is boolean, i.e. true or false
     console.log('Result: '+result)
  }
});
```

Comment: gave me the error TypeError: pem.verifiySigningChain is not a function

Comment: You have to add `var pem = require('pem');` to import `pem` module. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I have required pem already. What format does my cert and my ca have to be? When I hardcode it works but when I take it from the sqlite3 database it says pem.verify is not a function

Comment: added it above. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do this for NodeJS/Typescript

```js
import fs from 'fs';
    import crypto from 'crypto'

    const appleAppAttestationRootCaCert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../assets/AppleRootCA-G3.pem').toString();

    const credCert = new crypto.X509Certificate(Buffer.from(x5c[0], 'base64'))
    const caCert = new crypto.X509Certificate(Buffer.from(x5c[1], 'base64'))
    const appleCert = new crypto.X509Certificate(appleAppAttestationRootCaCert)

    const valid = credCert.verify(caCert.publicKey)
    console.log("Valid:", valid)
    caCert.verify(appleCert.publicKey);
    console.log("Valid with Apple Key:", valid)
```